# Activate alarm sound in Android

Tags: android, alert, alarm, ringtone

My alarm works well without silent and vibrate mode. When my phone is in silent and vibrate mode, How can I run the alarm. Also, how can I know alarm or music is finished.

```
private void mediaPlayerStart()
{
    try
    {
        Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        if(alert == null)
        {
            alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
            if(alert == null)
            {
                alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            }
        }
        ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), alert);
        ringtone.play();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if the user decided to mute his phone, it might be a good idea to keep it silent. However, if you're making an app for your own use, you can simply turn the volume up like so:

> AudioManager mgr=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
>   mgr.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(  AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM), AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);

Comment: I used this.             ringtone.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            ringtone.play();